# How to predict a time series based on a similar time series

Tags: time-series

I have a time series dataset with two columns. Each column is a time series. The two columns are highly correlated. As you can see in the plot their pattern changes simultaneously with a small offset. I want to create a prediction model which uses one of the columns as independent variable and predict the other column. I broke the datetime index to its components and created more features. Then I used an XGBoost model but the model error is significant ( Second plot for a zoomed time). I wonder what are other approaches to consider.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You only want to predict the value of series2 on the same timepoint?  (not predicting multiple points into the future, but a single point that is aligned on the same row/timepoint) ?  If so, xgboost is a good approach, what features did you create?

Comment: Correct! In fact the two series are the measurements from 2 different devices. For some period of times the blue device has missing values while the orange device has records and for some other times, the orange device has missing values while the blue one has records. I'd like to use one of the two devices' data to predict a variable, but I'd like to fill nulls using the other device's data.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your approach to treat this like a regression problem w/ xgboost.

**First**

The first thing I would look at, is are you adding enough features about the history? xgBoost will treat row as independent, but history matters - therefore you should add features like lags and moving averages over different historical windows.

For example, pretend your data looks like this:

```
|        dtm         | s1  | s2  |
|--------------------|-----|-----|
| ...                | ... | ... |
| 2021-01-17 0:00:00 | 515 | 100 |
| 2021-01-17 1:00:00 | 530 | 105 |
| 2021-01-17 2:00:00 | 504 |  95 |
| 2021-01-17 3:00:00 | 411 |  81 |
| ...                | ... | ... |
```

From your question, I imagine that you only did something like this:

```
|        dtm         | s1  |  y  | dtm_day | dtm_hr |
|--------------------|-----|-----|---------|--------|
| ...                | ... | ... |     ... |    ... |
| 2021-01-17 0:00:00 | 515 | 100 |      17 |      0 |
| 2021-01-17 1:00:00 | 530 | 105 |      17 |      1 |
| 2021-01-17 2:00:00 | 504 |  95 |      17 |      2 |
| 2021-01-17 3:00:00 | 411 |  81 |      17 |      3 |
| ...                | ... | ... |     ... |    ... |
```

The first thing I recommend is adding features like this:

```
|        dtm         | s1  |  y  | s2_lag1 | s2_lag2 | s2_avg_last3 | s2_avg_last24 |
|--------------------|-----|-----|---------|---------|--------------|---------------|
| ...                | ... | ... |     ... |     ... |          ... |           ... |
| 2021-01-17 0:00:00 | 515 | 100 |     ... |     ... |          ... |           ... |
| 2021-01-17 1:00:00 | 530 | 105 |     100 |     ... |          ... |           ... |
| 2021-01-17 2:00:00 | 504 |  95 |     105 |     100 |          ... |           ... |
| 2021-01-17 3:00:00 | 411 |  81 |      95 |     105 |          100 |           ... |
| ...                | ... | ... |     ... |     ... |          ... |           ... |
```

You can keep the time ones (if you think they matter), I just didn't retype them to save space. Also, don't forget to do this to s1 as well.

**Second**

The next consideration you should think about, is how is the xgBoost model making it's decisions. It's using cross-folds of randomly selected rows to hold out and use as validation.

The fact that your data is time-series means that this isn't fair. You can't really use a future data point to learn a relationship. Therefore my second suggestion is to be careful about the cross-validation setup and make sure you're testing only "relative" future data. This is sometimes called walk-forward validation or OTV or time validation.

When you search for this topic, be prepared to not get confused about the fact that this is usually done for forecasting problems, which you aren't doing exactly, so you'll have to spend time to really understand whats going on instead of copy/pasting code.

The way I do this, is I basically build out a partition_indicator and I will build my own folds. Then I tell xgBoost to respect those.

**Third**

The last thing you might look at, is the error function that xgBoost is using to make its decisions (aka optimization metric). It might be taking the safe route and following central tendency, because of the penalty associated with being wrong using RMSE. You can train your model with an error function that isn't as intuitive as RMSE, but still measure and report your models RMSE later.

One thing that might apply to your use-case is Quantile Loss, because by selecting the quantile you can influence the central tendency of the predictions to be up near the spikes. This is especially useful if your prediction has an unequal cost of being over-estimating vs under-estimating. Unfortunately I'm not sure if xgBoost supports that easily - you might try LightGBM instead.

**Fourth**

Another related concept is manipulating your dependent variable before predicting it. You may choose to calculate "difference of y from previous", ake "differencing". This means that the spikes will be more obvious and the seasonal trend up or down will become minimized. This makes your dataset more "stationary" which is ideal for the model. However from just glancing at your data, I don't see an overarching trend or seasonal pattern, so you probably can ignore this.

Another idea - You might also try making your target the "max of the next N points" if you care about predicting the spikes correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the through explanation. I strongly agree with the second idea you shared and will apply it immediately. The first idea is interesting and I did not know it about XGBoost. Although picking the periods of time is tricky since it's not a seasonal data, butI can apply some trial and error. Lastly, you hit the target with your last idea. This data is related to maximum wave height which is useful for energy production and I care about predicting the spike  and how long they last.